# Is it possible to determine if webservices are being used?

Tags: web-services, oc4j

There is an old OC4J server where 200+ web services are deployed. Now all have been ported to weblogic. The question is whether can I check if anyone is still accessing the webservices deployed in oc4j. Can't rely on app logs as this is quite old (not much standard followed)

If anyone is accessing is it possible to understand who is it?

PS: Am a newbie please help me in understanding this (if possible)  in detail.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Does the Weblogic log file (not the app log) show, or can you configure it to show, the queries? Parsing out the URLs should be simple.

Comment: Does it log the ip even if the application is not logging?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like TCPDump to locate in real-time traffic on the LAN where the destination and port number match the host/port of the running OC4J

Comment: This looks quite close. Thanks for pointing it out. Never knew about anything like this Using this can we see the ip from which call comes also the content rt. I think we can use "tcpdump dst x.x.x.x.